# Source for a quote from a commentary

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries

Allegedly the following quote is from Rav Abraham Saba's commentary on the Torah, Parashat Chaie Sarah:

> הרבה נחשים צייעונים וכלבים עזי נפש יש לו לקדוש ברוך הוא בעולמו. אם התחיבנו גלות, או לנו הכא ואוי לנו התם. בכל זאת אמרו חז"ל: תחת ישמעאל ולא תחת עכו"ם (שבת יא, ע"א). כנראה ישמעאל עצמו היה צדיק. בכתבי הקודש נזכרים הרבה אנשים שנקראו בשמו, וכן בתלמוד. אנחנו מזכירים בכל יום "רבי ישמעאל אומר," ולא מצינו "רבי עשו אומר," והרואה ישמעאל בן אברהם בחלום תפילתו נשמעת.

However, when searching the relevant section on Sefaria, I couldn't find it. Where can I find the full quote online?

Comment: Where did you find the alleged quotation? You can look through צרור המור yourself on beta.otzar.org (at least for the time being).

Comment: It's not showing up on AlHatorah.org...try downloading it from Hebrewbooks and searching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=2123&st=&pgnum=18) is a fuller quotation:

> ‮מי תכן את רוח מסבב הסבות? ואברהם מה כי תלינו עליו? הרבה נחשים צפענים וכלבים עזי נפש יש לו להקב״ה בעולמו. אם התחייבנו גלות - אוי לנו הכא. ואוי לנו התם. בכ״ז אמרו חז״ל תחת ישמעאל ולא תחת עכו״ם (שבת יא). כנראה ישמעאל עצמו היה צדיק. בכתבי הקדש נזכרים הרבה אנשים שנקראו בשמו. וכן בתלמוד. אנחנו מזכירים בכל יום ר׳ ישמעאל אומר. ולא מצינו ר׳ עשו אומר. - (השמעת מימיך אדם קורא שם בנו עשו?) והרואה ישמעאל [בן אברהם] בחלום תפילתו נשמעת. (ברכות נו):